# Grab first word on every line

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I've got a textfile where I want to catch every first word from:

> First name|All|01.01.55.41
>
> Second name||01.01.55.41
>
> Third name||01.01.55.41

Which I'm trying with:

```
function get_content() {
    $mailGeteld = NULL;
        $mailGeteld = file_get_contents("content.txt");
        $mailGeteld = explode("|",$mailGeteld);
        return $mailGeteld[0];
}
```

But now I'm only getting "First name", how can I loop it so the result is like:

> First name, Second name, Third name

Comment: don't `return`. that terminates your function... once you've got that out of the way, the rest should go better

Comment: You may want to look into `str_getcsv()` as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file` read's a file line by line.

```
function get_content() {
        $firstWords = array();
        $file = file("content.txt"); //read file line by line
        foreach ($file as $val) {
            if (trim($val) != '') { //ignore empty lines
                $expl = explode("|", $val);
                $firstWords[] = $expl[0]; //add first word to the stack/array
            }
        }
        return $firstWords; //return the stack of words - thx furas ;D
}

echo implode(', ', get_content()); //puts a comma and a blankspace between each collected word
```

Comment: you can add `return $firstWords`

Comment: At this time, I'm only getting "Array", but thx for the hint...I'll dive into it!

Comment: `$firstWords` IS an `array`, each element holding a word. use print_r($firstWords); or use another `foreach` loop, or the `implode` function. You can access each element like this: `echo $firstWords[0];`

Comment: How can I use the value? The function get_content is called like $result = get_content(); and I thought that I could show the array with '.$result.'?

Comment: you should be reading about the basics, you get into it very quick by trying examples. to show the array, you would use `'.$result[0].'` instead of just `'.$result.'`, where the `0` is the number of the index in the array. first word `[0]`, second line in `[1]` and so on

Comment: So I'll have to use '.$result[0].'? Hmm than I'm back where I started gheghe. I'm a Flash AS3 programmer and thought I could simply implement some php for it was more handy in this situation , but I'll solve it in AS for now :) Thx anyway Dan!

Comment: what do you want to do with the words? `echo implode(",", $result);` or `echo $result[0] . ', ' . $result[1] . ', ' . $result[3];`

Comment: Hmm figured it out, I was looking for     $result = implode(', ', get_content());

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SplFileObject`

```
$file = new SplFileObject("log.txt", "r");
$data = array();
while(! $file->eof()) {
    $data[] = array_shift(($file->fgetcsv("|")));
}
echo implode(", ", $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function operates on a single row. I propose you move `file_get_contents("content.txt");` out of function and iterate for each row and use your function each time.